# Radio button error in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am working on a project that includes an search function , currently the search works fine for that i am using an dropdown and select the value .
this is code that i am using with dropdown

```
<div class="form-group form-group-lg form-group-icon-left search"><i class="fa fa-plane input-icon"></i>
  <label>Select an option</label>
  <select class="typeahead form-control" name="search">
  <?php foreach($search_des as $sd) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $sd->des_category_id;?>">
             <?php echo $sd->des_category_name;?></option>
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <br>
</div>
```

Now as per our client requirement they need to display all the items with a radio button and also they want to submit the page by clicking on the radio 
. I tried to use radio button it doesnot works properly.
This is the code that ia am using with radio button.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Select an option</label>
  <?php foreach($search_des as $sd) { ?>
      <label>
      <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $sd->des_category_id;?>" type="radio">
     <?php echo $sd->des_category_name;?></label>
  <?php } ?>
  <br>
</div>
```

while using this all items are listing correctly but all the radio buttons are checked, also i dont know how to auto submit a form using a radio button.

Comment: You might want to start by giving your radio buttons a `name`, because otherwise they won’t be included in standard form submission at all. _“also i dont know how to auto submit a form using a radio button”_ - that sounds like something you should be able to research yourself though.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use Javascript to trigger submitting the form on click.

Add an event listener to the radio button being clicked, and then trigger the form to submit when that event happens.

Something like this should work, just change the IDs accordingly.

```
var form = document.getElementById("form-id");

document.getElementById("radio-id").addEventListener("click", function () {
  form.submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks ,only first records works fine other does not.

Comment: @JobyMathews can you describe what does not work means so I can help?

Comment: i had 3 records , here the form submission is working only with first record . ex: I had t1,t2,t3 whilie i click t1 the function works properly but rest of them does not works.

Comment: @JobyMathews I still don't understand what "does not work" means. Please describe the behavior you're getting very exactly. Does it not check the radio box? Does it not submit the form? Does it submit the form improperly? Have you tried using console.log() or debug() to see if the event listener is being triggered? Either way, my best guess is you don't have a unique ID for each radio box, or you haven't added the event listener for each radio box id and only did the first one.

Comment: Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/sjs96/q9a6v4ma/1/ only first record with the radio button is working

Comment: @JobyMathews It's as I said. You gave all three the same ID. ID must be unique, no two elements should have the same ID. You should either change so they all have unique IDs and add an event listener for each ID, or give them a class and use that to trigger them.

Answer (score 0):

You did not give the

```
name
```

attribute
to input

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Select an option</label>
         <?php foreach($search_des as $sd) { ?>
    <label>
    <input name="search" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $sd->des_category_id;?>" type="radio"><?php echo $sd->des_category_name;?></label>
                        <?php } ?>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are multiple things to be addressed in this question.

First, as mentioned above, you need to add the name tag to your radio button.

Secondly, you need to use JavaScript to submit the form on the click event of radio button. To get the click event set up, add the class at your radio button.

Posting the answer here with the link to my Codepen.

**Code**

```
<form name="theForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Select an option</label>
    <?php foreach($search_des as $sd) { ?>
      <label>
        <input class="form-control radioClass" value="<?php echo $sd->des_category_id;?>" type="radio" name="category">
        <?php echo $sd->des_category_name;?></label>
      <?php } ?>
    <br>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**
    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("radioClass"); // The radio button class we've added

```
var myFunction = function() {
    document.theForm.submit(); //theForm is the name of the form.
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);  //Adding listener to the click event.
}
```

You can play with the code (of course PHP script has been replaced with the dummy data) at this link: https://codepen.io/akshit_ij/pen/KydVXz

Let me know if it helps.